# How to setup react testing library with useLoaderData?

Tags: reactjs, testing, router, vitest

I have problem with react-router-dom 6.16 and react testing library with vitest.

**App.tsx**

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
{
    path: '/',
    element: (
        <Root />
    ),
    children: [
        {
            index: true,
            element: (
                    <OtherRoutes/>
            ),
        },
        {
            path: '/search',
            element: (
                    <SearchPage />
            ),
            loader: searchPageLoader,
        },
    ],
},
]);
```

const App = () => {
return (
<>





</>
);
};

**SearchPage.test.tsx**

```
describe('Search Page', () => {
test('Should render search page correctly', () => {
   const routes = [
        {
            path: '/',
            element: <Root />,
            children: [{
                    path: '/search',
                    element: <SearchPage />,
                    loader: searchPageLoader,
                },
            ],
        },
    ];
    const router = createMemoryRouter(routes, {
        initialEntries: ['/', '/search'],
        initialIndex: 1,
    });
    render(<RouterProvider router={router}/>);
    screen.debug();
});
});
```

The problem I have is that screen.debug() is outputting

```
<body>
 <div />
</body>
```

and nothing else.
I will add that everything works in the live version.
Any ideas on how to configure this correctly?

**searchPageLoader**

```
export function loader() {
return queryClient.fetchQuery({
queryKey: ['vehicles'],
queryFn: fetchFn,
});
}

export async function fetchFn() {
const url = 'url';

const response = await fetch(url);

if (!response.ok) {
const error = new Error('An error occurred while retrieving data');
throw error;
}

const data = await response.json();
return data;
}
```

Comment: Show the code of `searchPageLoader`

Comment: ok, i added the code to the main question